# Unable to find source code for xv6 function gets

Tags: c, io, xv6

I am currently exploring xv6 source code and found this line in the code of function getcmd (booklet: line 8688):

```
gets(buf, nbuf);
```

I tried to find the source for function gets in the booklet (https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2018/xv6/xv6-rev11.pdf) and in the official repo (https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public) but didn't manage to do that. Can you please provide me a link or explain why there is no source for the function gets?

Comment: isn't `gets()` already deprecated?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Very valid, but in this case, I believe this is for educational purpose and not the standard library thing,so...

Comment: @SouravGhosh Not to mention it's not the (former) standard C function. This one actually have a buffer-length argument. :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I had the same thought as you sir at first sight, but then i googled. "xv6" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in [ulib.c](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/308a3b88c9e59b9065f1af9cdd2e0369cdfd0823/ulib.c) file in the same repo. It is defined as

```
char*
gets(char *buf, int max)
{
  int i, cc;
  char c;

  for(i=0; i+1 < max; ){
    cc = read(0, &c, 1);
    if(cc < 1)
      break;
    buf[i++] = c;
    if(c == '\n' || c == '\r')
      break;
  }
  buf[i] = '\0';
  return buf;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! but why the source for ulib.c isn't present in the official booklet? should i open an issue in their repo?

Comment: @Azatik1000 It's present in the repo...should that not be enough? Sure you can open a bug, but is that really worth it? Maybe we should just look a little harder, sometimes that's all it takes.